# Track git changes in subfolders in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository, project, subdirectory

I have a project that has a root git repository that have multiple subfolders that are also git repositories. My structure is like this:

`/Project`
`/Project/module/libs`
`/Project/module/src`

Every folder has a separate git repository, because `libs` and `src` are used from another projects.

In root project I have ignored the others `libs` and `src`, but I want them to be tracked from the VSCode (Web Storm does it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and clone the main project elsewhere, then try and add the Git repos `libs` and `src` as [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (assuming that those repos are already pushed somewhere)

```
cd /path/to/Project
git submodule add /url/repo/libs module/libs
git submodule add /url/repo/src module/src
```

Then you can open Project in VSCode: it should track as well libs and src.

VSCode is still developing its [Git submodule support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7829), starting with [PR 36313](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/36313).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That command creates a file .gitmodules that afterwards can be edited. I added both submodules and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm 2 days new to vsCode (in 2021) and had the same problem during setup. I closed the Parent Workspace that was ignoring the nested repos and created a new workspace of the nested repos. VsCode started showing the changes like it did with the parent.  Then I saved the workspace and added the parent repo to the new repo with the nested repos and everything is now being tracked and displayed.